# Filename is getting corrupted randomly when using os.walk()

Tags: python, filenames, os.walk

I'm trying to get all the files within a folder using os.walk(), the code I'm using is:

```
#Define folder  and pattern to find
rootPath = "./root_folder"
pattern = "*MATCH*"

#Look for all the files with "MATCH" on its file name
Final_List = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        Final_List.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
        print(root,"\\", filename)
```

I'm trying to debbug the problem by printing the root and the filename (as below), but every now and then there is a corrupted "filename" like the "File4 name.rtf". I have another version of the same file as "~$le4 name.rtf". The problem is after this step I'm reading all the files to extract the text but I'm getting an error while reading this files with the "~$" at the beggining of the name.

Below, I tried to cover all the different configurations of file names, some of them have ".", others have "-", other have spaces " ", and so on.

```
./root_folder\folder1 \ File1 name E. example.docx
./root_folder\folder1 \ File2 name_.docx
./root_folder\folder1 \ File4 name.rtf
./root_folder\folder1\inside_folder1 \ File3 name example.rtf
./root_folder\folder2 \ File4 name.rtf
./root_folder\folder2 \ File5 name another-example.rtf
./root_folder\folder2 \ ~$le4 name.rtf
./root_folder\folder2 \ File6 name.another.example.pdf
```

I was looking for patterns among the files to see if it's related with the file name or the dir name but it doesn't looks like. I also copy-paste it the same file that is somehow corrupted (i.e. "File4 name.rtf") in other folders, and it's working fine, in other folders the same file is read properly.

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: looks very much like MS Word backup files... the files are hidden so you don't see them in the explorer, but they _are_ there.

Comment: I have activated the function "View" -> "Hidden items", but there are no more files.

Comment: Hidden / System items. There's one more level: hidden files used by system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that those files are there, but hidden by Windows explorer.

But `os.walk` doesn't filter those files. It just filters `.` and `..`.

Those files starting by `~$` are Microsoft Word backup files. When Word opens a file, it creates the same file name, but for the 2 first chars, which are `~$`.

(the only strange fact is that those backups are usually visible, well, ...)

If Word crashes or is killed, this backup file remains.

You should ignore them. For instance by changing the pattern like this:

```
pattern = "[!~][!$]*MATCH*.rtf"
```

or by adding:

```
if not filename.startswith("~$"):
```

in your loop

(pattern filtering is not exactly the same since it will filter files starting by `~` but not followed by `$`, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Yes, that workaround did the trick. I was approaching the issue from a different perspective. It's very weird all the files are closed and I can't see any other file even if the view hidden files option is flagged. Thanks!

Comment: as I hinted, there are 2 levels of hidden files in windows. Hidden and "operating system hidden" (not sure of the english term). You have to tick another box to see them. Anyway, glad you sorted it out.